# SQL: How to see how many items in a list, appear in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I don't care about US cities, but just as an example - say I have a table of US cities, and I want to know how many from a list are in that table.

```
SELECT
     COUNT(*)

FROM
     CITY_TABLE C

WHERE
    --the list
    C.NAME IN ('San Francisco', 'Springfield', 'Murderville')
```

The above would give how many hits - maybe 70, who knows., but what I really want is a response from 0-3.

i.e., how many from my list, appear in the table.

You could just run the above query, then use Excel to get the answer.
If in a more typical programming language, you could run a loop that has an x + 1 in it.

But is there a way to do this directly in an SQL query?  Specifically T-SQL I guess, but I'm kinda curious in general.

Comment: Try Select top 3 * FROM
     CITY_TABLE C
WHERE
    C.NAME IN ('San Francisco', 'Springfield', 'Murderville')

Comment: But if say - San Francisco appeared multiple times in the list, that could give the wrong number.  And then you'd say - OK use a common table expression to pull a unique version of the table and query that - and we're back to - sorry, I'm dumb - I simplified my question to the point of asking the *wrong* question.  I was thinking more for situations using LIKE...I'm going to have to repost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this.

```
SELECT
     COUNT(DISTINCT C.NAME)
FROM
     CITY_TABLE C
WHERE
    --the list
    C.NAME IN ('San Francisco', 'Springfield', 'Murderville')
```

Comment: That answers the question, but I realize I simplified things into asking the wrong question!  I was thinking more for a situation where LIKE is involved, so say - San Francisco 218 and San Francisco B9 would be distinct, but I only wanted to know there was a hit on LIKE 'San Francisco%'   I'm going to repost a better phrased question...

Comment: There are some ways to making this but it's totally different question and has a different answer. For example, if your district name at the end of the state name, you should remove it before count them. I recommend to you create a new question for this.

Comment: Yes, completely different question.  And I am, thanks.